# Is there a Libadalang function that works similarly to Traverse_Control and traveral in general in ASIS?

Tags: ada

I am trying to convert the libraries in an Ada program from ASIS to Libadalang, and I am having trouble finding conversions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an ASIS or libadalang expert, but a quick look in the docs suggests that the (generic) `Traverse_Element` function from package `Asis.Iterator` ([description](http://docs.adacore.com/asis-docs/html/asis_ug/asis_ug/asis_overview.html#asis-iterator), [code](http://www.sigada.org/WG/asiswg/specs/asis-iterator.ads)) can (more or less) be mapped to libadalang's `Traverse` function defined in package `Libadalang.Analysis`:

```
function Traverse
  (Node  : Ada_Node'Class;
   Visit : access function (Node : Ada_Node'Class) return Visit_Status)
   return Visit_Status;
--  Given the parent node for a subtree, traverse all syntactic nodes of
--  this tree, calling the given function on each node in prefix order
--  (i.e. top-down). The order of traversing subtrees follows the order
--  of declaration of the corresponding attributes in the grammar. The
--  traversal is controlled as follows by the result returned by Visit:
--
--     Into   The traversal continues normally with the syntactic
--            children of the node just processed.
--
--     Over   The children of the node just processed are skipped and
--            excluded from the traversal, but otherwise processing
--            continues elsewhere in the tree.
--
--     Stop   The entire traversal is immediately abandoned, and the
--            original call to Traverse returns Stop.
```

with

```
type Visit_Status is (Into, Over, Stop);
```

There also seems to be another iterator package, `Libadalang.Iterators`, which provides even more iterator capabilities.

AdaCore has several blog posts available with examples on how to use `libadalang`'s API. For example:

- [An Expedition into Libadalang](https://blog.adacore.com/an-expedition-into-libadalang) (Demonstrates the `Traverse` function)
- [A Further Expedition into Libadalang](https://blog.adacore.com/save-time-with-libadalang-helpers-app)

Comment: For Traverse_Control in ASIS, there are elements such as ASIS.Continue that allow you to control traversal, which is more of what I am having difficulty with. Do you have any ideas about whether or not that can be implemented in Libadalang?

Comment: @libada It seems that (e.g.) `ASIS.Continue` maps (semantically) to `Visit_Status'(Into)` (I might be missing your point here...). Consider making the original question a little bit more concrete in order to give the people willing to help more context on the actual problem at hand (i.e. by adding a minimal example or by explaining the purpose of (some part of the) ASIS application to be migrated).